# Core Graphics - My triangle/arc is too pointy

Tags: ios, core-graphics, pie-chart

I'm drawing the 'slices' in a custom pie chart in Core Graphics, using a `UIBezierPath` and the `[path addArcWithCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:]` method. My problem is that often the pointy end of the slice actually juts *past* the center point, intruding into other slices space.

Is there a way to 'round' this edge?

---

Here is the code im using to draw the path

```
[path moveToPoint:center];
[path addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:interiorAngle endAngle:totalAngle clockwise:YES];
[path addLineToPoint:center];
[path closePath];
```

---

Here is an image of the problem:

[image: The bottom left blue sector 'bleeds' into the larger blue sector near the middle]

The white pointy end of the blue piece on the lower left intrudes slightly into the large blue piece in the upper right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not "past" the center point. Your confusion lies in the fact that you're stroking the path. When you stroke a path, the stroke lies centered upon the path, and therefore half of the stroke is outside the path and half of the stroke is inside the path. If you want an accurate stroke, you have two options:

1. Fill your path with your stroke color, then construct another path that's inset into your first one by the desired line width, and then fill that path with your fill color. This will simulate an "inside" stroke, although it's not usable if your stroke or fill colors are semi-transparent.
2. Clip to your path, double the stroke width, and then stroke your path. The clipping will force the stroke to only draw inside the path. However, this may not look quite "accurate" at corners (not really sure) since it's doubling the stroke width rather than calculating the "desired" path.

Alternatively, you could try just setting the `lineJoinStyle` to something other than `kCGLineJoinMiter`. With the default miter style, the lines actually draw out as far as they need to from the corner in order to meet, which means they can go past 1/2 the line width. If you use `kCGLineJoinRound` or `kCGLineJoineBevel` they cannot go past 1/2 the line width. This may not be quite accurate, but it may be good enough for what you want.

Comment: I think it'd work to use miter for the fills and bevel or round for the strokes, perhaps with a circle equal in diameter to the line width at the center to make sure that's covered.

Comment: Another possible solution would be to simply do all the strokes first (they could even be done in a single stroke, if they're guaranteed to always all be the same color) and then all the fills.

Comment: @PeterHosey: The idea of "use miter for the fills" doesn't make sense. Fills don't have a join style. They don't ever go beyond the path, period. The join style here applies exclusively to strokes.

Comment: @Dfowj: Glad to hear it. That's certainly the simplest solution, but there are cases where people want a stroke that doesn't go outside their path, because they need to be precise, and that's where my other 2 suggestions are used.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect the problem is with the line width of the white line.  For example, a line that is 8 points wide, would have 4 points on either side of the path.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the problem in that image (which slice is showing it?), but I can suggest that you remove the `addLineToPoint:` message. It isn't necessary; `closePath` will return to the center, since that's where you started.

Comment: His problem is the acute angle has a really pointy tip that extends far past his desired path, and if you look in at the big blue wedge you can see the pointy end of the opposite small blue wedge intruding.